# Gridster not appearing under jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I'm using Gridster to render a layout of tiles in my app, using NodeBB as a base.

The code is as follows:

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/gridster.js"></script>

<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".gridster ul").gridster({
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [175, 175],

        serialize_params: function(wi, wgd) {
            console.log($(wi).attr('id'));
            return {
                id: $(wi).attr('id'),
                col: wgd.col,
                row: wgd.row,
                size_x: wgd.size_x,
                size_y: wgd.size_y
            };
        },

        draggable: {
            start: function () {
                dragged = 1;
            },
            stop: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    dragged = 0;
                }, 5);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I've tried to initialise Gridster in a `<script>` tag, but when I run it I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

when trying to access gridster (`$('.gridster ul').gridster( \\ ..`). jQuery is fine, it's just Gridster.

Why?

Comment: Yes. In Chrome developer tools, it shows the script was loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like perhaps you have used the sourcefile, rather than the compiled version of gridster. Did you download from GitHub? Use `dist/jquery.gridster.min.js`, rather than `src/jquery.gridster.js`

For future reference, the version in `src/` is for use when being compiled by [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: The file I used was the version compiled and minified by the developer (gridster.min.js) and it worked before placing in NodeBB. Thank you anyway!

Comment: So did you figure it out or is it still not working?

Comment: I switched to using the NodeBB built in system for managing grids.